# In Java, How do I cast a Realm Object into the class I wish to write to the Database?

Tags: android, class, object, casting, realm

I am currently working on a project where my Database has a very large number of tables (Approx 60 total). I am working to create the Database Helper class that will function as the writer/ reader to/ from the database. And example of my write method would be this:

```
public static void executeInsertInto(final Context context, final UserData passedObject){
    //Generate a realm object from the context
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            //Begin a transaction, create a new item from the passed object, and commit.
            realm.beginTransaction();
            UserData itemToWrite = realm.copyToRealm(passedObject);
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    });
    //Close the realm object to prevent leaks
    if (realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, I manually created an object of type UserData; The problem is, I either have to repeat this a total of 60 times (for the many types of objects / tables) or come up with a better way. This leads me to my question, is there a way to create an object using the type of passed object to determine the class? Something like the code below did not want to work as I am doing something fundamentally wrong with my Java code:

```
    public static void executeInsertInto(final Context context, final RealmObject passedObject){
            //Generate a realm object from the context
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    //Begin a transaction, create a new item from the passed object, and commit.
                    realm.beginTransaction();
//The below line is flawed in that you cannot create an object that way, 
//But hopefully it illustrates what I am trying to accomplish
                    passedObject.getClass() itemToWrite = (passedObject.getClass()) realm.copyToRealm(passedObject);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                }
            });
            //Close the realm object to prevent leaks
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
```

Anyone have any Ideas? I would greatly appreciate it!

EDIT:
Just to clarify further, Take Realm out of the picture for one second, assuming I have two classes (**Class Car** and **Class Bike**), both of which extend to **Class Transportation**, if I am passed class transportation as an argument, how can I determine which type is being passed and then once I do, how do I create a new object with that information?

-Sil

Comment: Note the executeTransaction() will perform the beginTransaction() and commitTransaction() for you. That's the point of the executeTransaction(). Alternatively you can just leave out the whole executeTransaction() stuff, and use the body of execute() strait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Realm classes extends RealmObject so you can use generics to accomplish it:

```
public static <T extends RealmObject> void executeInsertInto(final Context context, final T passedObject){
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            T itemToWrite = realm.copyToRealm(passedObject);
        }
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Granted, I still had to pass in some type of identifier variable (I chose final ints that I setup to be constants to identify the correct class) in order to cast it.